# defining same elements in X macro C

Tags: c, macros, x-macros

I have been exploring X macro and I created this table

```
#define FAULT_TABLE(FAULT) \
FAULT(INVALID,                            FAULT_CATEGORY_NONE, action_none) \
FAULT(COMMS_FAILURE,                       FAULT_CATEGORY_1, action_1) \
FAULT(QUEUE_FAILURE,                        FAULT_CATEGORY_1, action_1) \
FAULT(SENSOR_FAILURE,                FAULT_CATEGORY_1, action_1) \
FAULT(FAILED_OP                     FAULT_CATEGORY_1, action_1)
```

I just wanted to know if I can have same values and generate an enum out of it . I meant the enum out of 2nd column in the table .

And how do I assign the same function call to the fault codes above

**Update**
Just to add more clarity and context: When any of these fault is reported , my fault handler would be looking at the category and function to execute . Some faults have the same action and belong to same category . So I am trying to figure if this can be done through X macro .

So I just want enum to expanded as

```
typedef enum {
FAULT_CATEGORY_NONE,
FAULT_CATEGORY_1,
FAULT_CATEGORY_N,
}
```

Also I would the functions defined in table to expanded as Jump table.

Comment: Simply generate the enum outside this X macro. There's nothing in the posted X macro that's useful for creating the enum. It rather seems to assume that the enum is already created. For example, did you consider writing `typedef enum {
FAULT_CATEGORY_NONE,
FAULT_CATEGORY_1,
FAULT_CATEGORY_N,
} my_type;` ? If not then why not? Too easy, too readable?

Answer (score 1):

> I just wanted to know if I can have same values and generate an enum out of it . I meant the enum out of 2nd column in the table .

You cannot duplicate enum constants, but you can give different enum constants the same value.  So, for example, you could do this:

```
#define FAULT_CATEGORY_NONE 0
#define FAULT_CATEGORY_1 1

#define FAULT_TABLE(FAULT) \
FAULT(INVALID,                            FAULT_CATEGORY_NONE) \
FAULT(COMMS_FAILURE,                       FAULT_CATEGORY_1) \
FAULT(QUEUE_FAILURE,                        FAULT_CATEGORY_1) \
FAULT(SENSOR_FAILURE,                FAULT_CATEGORY_1) \
FAULT(FAILED_OP,                     FAULT_CATEGORY_1)

#define FAULT(x, y) x ## _CAT = (y),

enum category {
FAULT_TABLE(FAULT)
DUMMY_CAT
};
```

That expands to

```
enum category {
    INVALID_CAT = (0),        COMMS_FAILURE_CAT = (1), QUEUE_FAILURE_CAT = (1),
    SENSOR_FAILURE_CAT = (1), FAILED_OP_CAT = (1),     DUMMY_CAT
};
```

(extra whitespace added for clarity).

But I don't see how X macros are actually helping you there.  In particular, it's suspicious that you present a different definition of `FAULT_TABLE` for the sub-question about assigning functions.

The X macro approach provides some traction when you can re-use the same list (`FAULT_TABLE`, here) for multiple definitions of `X` (`FAULT`).  Your example does not appear to be well suited to that, however, as each use appears to require the list to provide different data.  I guess you could cram it all into the same list by relying on `FAULT` to accept an additional parameter, but you would probably be better off just creating regular tables.  For example:

```
enum fault {
    INVALID, COMMS_FAILURE, QUEUE_FAILURE, SENSOR_FAILURE, FAILED_OP 
};

const int fault_category[] = {
    [INVALID] = FAULT_CATEGORY_NONE,
    [COMMS_FAILURE] = FAULT_CATEGORY_1,
    [QUEUE_FAILURE] = FAULT_CATEGORY_1,
    [SENSOR_FAILURE] = FAULT_CATEGORY_1,
    [FAILED_OP] = FAULT_CATEGORY_1
};

const void (*fault_action[])(void) = {
    [INVALID] = action_none,
    [COMMS_FAILURE] = action_1,
    [QUEUE_FAILURE] = action_1,
    [SENSOR_FAILURE] = action_1,
    [FAILED_OP] = action_2
};
```

You could certainly employ X macros to generate such code, but I don't think you would save much space, and I think the result would be considerably *less* clear.

---

**With respect to the question update**

You seem to be looking to use the X macro approach to select and generate output only for each distinct value of some argument to the `X` macro on some given pass through the list.  I hesitate to say it's impossible, because clever people have squeezed some fairly surprising behaviors out of the preprocessor, but **I am confident in saying that there is no *straightforward* way to make the preprocessor do it**.

The jump table is easier, because you want analogous output for each invocation of `FAULT`.  Thus, you might do this ...

```
#define FAULT_TABLE(FAULT) \
FAULT(INVALID,                            FAULT_CATEGORY_NONE, action_none) \
FAULT(COMMS_FAILURE,                       FAULT_CATEGORY_1, action_1) \
FAULT(QUEUE_FAILURE,                        FAULT_CATEGORY_1, action_1) \
FAULT(SENSOR_FAILURE,                FAULT_CATEGORY_1, action_1) \
FAULT(FAILED_OP,                     FAULT_CATEGORY_1, action_1) 

#define ENUM_CONST(fault, cat, action)   fault,
#define ACTION_ENTRY(fault, cat, action) [fault] = action,

enum fault {
    FAULT_TABLE(ENUM_CONST)
    DUMMY_FAULT
};

const void (*fault_action[])(void) = {
    FAULT_TABLE(ACTION_ENTRY)
    0
};
```

But again, I don't see much advantage there over just writing the enum and jump table directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer . I have edited the question to make it more clear . Hope you understand it better now . I have to create a fault table with multiple parametres . I do not want to be writing enum or update the table every time I change the fault

Comment: @ro88, I have updated this answer to address the changes you made to the question.

Comment: Minor bug: it should be `void (* const fault_action[])(void)`. Or better yet: `typedef void fault_action_t (void);` ... `const fault_action_t* fault_action[] = ...`

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you! Just couple of  question . Why do you have `0` in the `const void (*fault_action[])(void)`. And my compiler throws an error for multiple definition of  `fault_action`.                                                                                               Is there a problem with my code here       `typedef void (*ACTION_POINTER_TYPE)(void);
#define ACTION_POINTER(a,b,c,d,e) [a] = c,
const FAILUREMGR_ACTION_POINTER_TYPE fault_action_table[NUM_FAULTS] = {
    FAULT_TABLE(ACTION_POINTER)
    };`

Comment: @ro88, I have the zero in the `fault_action` table because otherwise, the code is invalid on account of the trailing comma after the last real item.  It is effectively a null function pointer.  There are ways to work around such issues with X macros, but all would require modifying your `FAULT_TABLE` definition one way or another.

Comment: @ro88, I present several code variations in this answer.  None of them, as expanded by the preprocessor, contain multiple definitions of `fault_action`.  Each one compiles successfully for me.  You do need to choose *one*, however, else you will indeed have multiple-definition problems.  And if you have your own, separate declaration of `fault_action` then that also could produce multiple definitions, in which case you would want to change one of the names.

Comment: @ro88, and yes, the variation presented in your comment has exactly the problem that I solve in my example code by including a 0 at the end of the definition of `fault_action`: there is a trailing comma in the initializer list.  It might also have an issue if `NUM_FAULTS` expands to a number smaller than the number of initializers.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @JohnBollinger. Yes was missing 0 in my code